# Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse of matrix using Singular Value Decomposition

Tags: c, matrix, linear-algebra, svd

I am trying to compute the pseudoinverse of a matrix in C code. Specifically, I am trying to compute the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse using singular value decomposition (SVD). I know there are some libraries out there for SVD but I am trying not to use any external libraries such as LAPACK or OpenCV. I found the following source code online and have been trying to follow it:

http://www.mymathlib.com/c_source/matrices/linearsystems/singular_value_decomposition.c

Sorry, it seems pretty long but a lot of it is good documentation. I am particularly interested in "After performing the singular value decomposition for A, call Singular_Value_Decomposition_Inverse to calculate the pseudo-inverse of A." Where I am struggling (I think mostly due to my inexperience with c) is how to go about running this source code.

My current main function:

```
int main(){

 double A[4][4] = {{0, 0, 0, 0,},
     {0, 2, 1, 2}, 
     {2, 1, 0, 1}, 
     {2, 0, 1, 4}};
    #define M 4                                                             //
    #define N 4                                                             //
    double U[M][N];                                                        //
    double V[N][N];                                                        //
    double D[N];                                                           //
    double Astar[N][M];                                                    //
    double tolerance;
   
// here add whatever function need to be run 

   Singular_Value_Decomposition_Inverse(double* U, double* D, double* V,  
                        double tolerance, int nrows, int ncols, double *Astar);

   int i,j,k;
   double *pu, *pv, *pa;
   double dum;

   dum = DBL_EPSILON * D[0] * (double) ncols;
   if (tolerance < dum) tolerance = dum;
   for ( i = 0, pv = V, pa = Astar; i < ncols; i++, pv += ncols) 
      for ( j = 0, pu = U; j < nrows; j++, pa++) 
        for (k = 0, *pa = 0.0; k < ncols; k++, pu++)
           if (D[k] > tolerance) *pa += *(pv + k) * *pu / D[k];
           printf(" The pseudo-inverse of A = UDV' is \n", )

}
```

I am not sure if I am on the right track so any guidance would be great. I am trying to understand what I am doing so please refrain from posting a completed solution. Just looking for some guidance :)

I do not understand what is meant by the following:

```
//     After performing the singular value decomposition for A, call          //
//     Singular_Value_Decomposition to solve the equation Ax = B or call      //
//     Singular_Value_Decomposition_Inverse to calculate the pseudo-inverse   //
//     of A.                                                                  //
```

"After performing the singular value decomposition for A" Don't I have to call the Singular_Value_Decomposition first or are they referring to Singular_Value_Decomposition_Solve and it is a typo?

The problem I am currently facing is I'm not sure how to use the source code provided to generate an output. I understand the logic to calculate pinv is completed but I am not sure how to actually put it all together. I have started off with creating a main function to initialize some variables and my input matrix. After my initialization I am not sure what to do next

Comment: Stack Overflow works best when you specify a problem statement.  What is the problem with your code?  Are you not getting the output you are expecting?

Comment: Neither of these is necessarily a partof whatever problem you're encountering, but … The final `printf()` is mis-indented by 4 levels of indentation.  That won't help anybody.  You declare the function`Singular_Value_Decomposition_Inverse()` but you neither call nor implement it.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, the problem I am currently facing is I'm not sure how to use the source code provided to generate an output. I understand the logic to calculate pinv is completed but I am not sure how to actually put it all together. I have started off with creating a main function to initialize some variables and my input matrix. After my initialization I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have updated a problem statement, thank you for your feedback

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So the part I am actually struggling with is how to call/implement the Singular_Value_Decomposition_Inverse() in my main function.

Comment: Here's how I'd go about it: implement it in Octave using high level primitives, then progressively reduce the level of those primitives to the most basic of operators that are "trivial" to implement at least for small operand sizes (basic matrix algebra, with vectors being single-wide matrices, i.e. row or column matrices as needed - no need for special-casing those usually). You've got high-level Octave code to help you out. You'll also be able to easily translate relevant formulas from a textbook to high-level code and start that way.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Hi, I dont understand what you mean by 'octave'. Are you saying to test each of the functions individually even simple operations like matrix multiplication

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h> // add
#include<stdlib.h> // add

#include <string.h>              // required for memcpy()
#include <float.h>               // required for DBL_EPSILON
#include <math.h>                // required for fabs(), sqrt();

#define MAX_ITERATION_COUNT 30   // Maximum number of iterations

...
...
...

int main(){

int M=4;
int N=4;

 double A[4][4] = {{0, 0, 0, 0},
                   {0, 2, 1, 2}, 
                   {2, 1, 0, 1},
                   {2, 0, 1, 4} };

                                

     double U[M][N];                                                        
     double V[N][N];                                                        
     double singular_values[N];                                             
     double* dummy_array;                                                   
                                                                            
    // (your code to initialize the matrix A)                                 
     dummy_array = (double*) malloc(N * sizeof(double));                    
     if (dummy_array == NULL) {printf(" No memory available\n"); exit(0); } 
                                                                            
     double err = Singular_Value_Decomposition((double*) A, M, N, (double*) U, singular_values, (double*) V, dummy_array);   //
                                                                            
     free(dummy_array);                                                     
     if (err < 0) printf(" Failed to converge\n");                          
     else { printf(" The singular value decomposition of A is \n");         
                                                               
        //printf("%d", err);
        
        /*
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        
        printf("%f\n", singular_values[i]);
        
        }
        */
        
        /*
        for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<M;j++){
        
        //printf("\t%0.3f" , A[i][j]);
        printf("\t%0.3f" , U[i][j]);
        //printf("\t%0.3f" , V[i][j]);
        
            }
        //printf("\n");
        //printf("\n");
        printf("\n");   
    }
    */
    } 
 
    double D[4]={5.408, 2.053, 1.59, 0};                                                        
    double Astar[N][M]; 
                                            
    double tolerance;                                                      
 
 /*
    double D[4][4] = {{5.408, 0, 0, 0},
                      {0, 2.053, 0, 0}, 
                      {0, 0, 0, 1.590},
                      {0, 0, 0,      0} };
        */
 
     Singular_Value_Decomposition_Inverse((double*) U, D, (double*) V,
                    tolerance, M, N, (double*) Astar);  
     printf(" The pseudo-inverse of A = UDV' is \n");     
        for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<M;j++){
        printf("\t%0.6f" , Astar[i][j]);
            }
        printf("\n");
        }
 return 0;
 
}
```

output:

```
 The pseudo-inverse of A = UDV' is
        0.000000        -0.217970       0.461692        0.012779
        0.000000        0.359000        0.269341        -0.256465
        -0.000000       0.128219        -0.153902       0.051306
        -0.000000       0.076937        -0.192391       0.230824

--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.06935 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).